# C++ change parent class based on option

Tags: c++, class

There is a **Student** class inherited from **Person**.
And there is **Student** class inherited from **University**.
I want to change the parent class **Person**, **University** based on the option without rewriting **Student** such as  **Student1** and **Student2** (because student class is very complicated).
Here is the example code.

```
class Person {
  void f() {printf("I'm person")}
};

class University {
  void f() {printf("I'm university")}
};

class Student1 : public Person {
  void g() {f()}
};
class Student2 : public University {
  void g() {f()} // I don't wan't to rewrite this!
};

if (option.person) {
  Student1 student;
}
else {
  Student2 student;
}
```

Comment: Is `option.person` known at compile-time?

Comment: Also, what version of C++ are you using? C++20 has a whole host of useful things for this.

Comment: I'm using c++ 17, but I can use c++ 20. please share if there is any optinion.

Comment: option.person is unkown at compile-time

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to have separate classes for each person

Comment: I don't think inheritance is what you want here. Inheritance is only useful in narrow subsets of "Is-A" relationships. A `Student` is *not* a `University`. Even if that was some other class that made more sense, I would recommend [using composition instead of inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Comment: If you find yourself struggling with your inheritance hierarchy and end up trying to do weird/impossible things with it, that may be a sign to step back and re-evaluate whether your class structure truly makes sense - in this case, the question of whether a Student is a University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can't know what `option.person` is at compile-time, we need to find a way to work around that at runtime.

One option for doing so is `std::variant`, which can store any number of different types; but does so at the cost of always having the same size as the largest templated type.

As an example, if I did this:

```cpp
std::variant<char, int> myVariant = '!';
```

Even though `myVariant` holds a `char` (1 byte), it uses 4 bytes of RAM because an `int` is 4 bytes.

#### Using Variants

Rather than inheriting from different objects that do not share a common base at compile-time, we can maintain the 'base' type as a variable within `Student` instead.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <concepts>

class Person {
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a person!\n";
    }
};
class University {
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a university!\n";
    }
};

class Student {
public:
    using variant_t = std::variant<Person, University>;
    variant_t base;

    // Here we accept an rvalue of any type, then we move it to the 'base' variable.
    //  if the type is not a Person or University, a compiler error is thrown.
    Student(auto&& owner) : base{ std::move(owner) } {}

    void g()
    {
        // METHOD 1:  Using std::holds_alternative & std::get
        //             This has the advantage of being the simplest & easiest to understand.
        if (std::holds_alternative<Person>(base))
            std::get<Person>(base).f();
        else if (std::holds_alternative<University>(base))
            std::get<University>(base).f();


        // METHOD 2:  Using std::get_if
        //             This has the advantage of being the shortest.
        if (auto* person = std::get_if<Person>(&base))
            person->f();
        else if (auto* university = std::get_if<University>(&base))
            university->f();


        // METHOD 3:  Using std::visit
        //             This has the advantage of throwing a meaningful compiler error if-
        //             -we modify `variant_t` and end up passing an unhandled type.
        std::visit([](auto&& owner) {
            using T = std::decay_t<decltype(owner)>;
            if constexpr (std::same_as<T, Person>)
                owner.f(); //< this calls  `Person::f()`
            else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, University>)
                owner.f(); //< this calls  `University::f()`
            else static_assert(false, "Not all potential variant types are handled!");
        }, base);
    }
};
```

In this example, I showed 3 different methods of accessing the underlying value of `base`.
As a result, the output is:
[image: output]

Further reading:

- [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)
- [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get)
- [`std::get_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if)
- [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: While this is a good simple example of how `std::variant` works, I'm not sure it's the right tool for the job here. You could, for instance, just make `Student` a template and give it a member variable of the templated type.

Comment: This is true, but it will prevent you from storing it in containers like `std::vector` that only allow one type.  I do agree that templates are the preferable solution here if at all possible though.

Comment: Indeed, but OP's original question also forbids you from storing `Student1` and `Student2` in the same container. If that is necessary, you can still have a base class that the class templates inherit from, or use another technique like type erasure or having `University`/`Person` inherit from the same class and store a pointer to `base`.